# Friend class in C++ not allowing access to private member attributes

Tags: c++, class, friend

I recently started C++ and to be completely honest my lecturer isn't much help, I am trying to give a linked list friend access to a node class. From what I can see I have declared everything I need, but I still cant access the Node private members , if somebody could see something im missing that would be great!

My node header file:

````
```#ifndef NodeofBook_h
#define NodeofBook_h

#include <stdio.h>
#include "Book.h"

class ListOfBooks;
//
class NodeofBook {
    
    friend class ListOfBooks;
    
private:
    NodeofBook* next;
    Book* theBook;
    
public:
    
};


#endif /* NodeofBook_h */
````

My linked list header file :

```
#ifndef ListOfBooks_h
#define ListOfBooks_h

#include <stdio.h>
#include "NodeofBook.h"

class ListOfBooks {
    
private:
    
public:
    ListOfBooks();
    void insertBack(int);
    void displayList();
    int deleteMostRecent();
    int deleteInt(int pos);
};


#endif /* ListOfBooks_h */
```

My Linked List cpp file:

```
#include "ListOfBooks.h"

int ListOfBooks(){
    
    return 0;
}

ListOfBooks::ListOfBooks(){
    theBook->title = "noTitleYet";
    theBook->isbn = 0000;
    next = NULL;
}
```

I am getting an error stating **Use of undeclared identifier 'theBook'**

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: `ListOfBooks` has access to private member variables of `NodeofBook` instances, but inside the `ListOfBooks()` constructot there's no such `NodeofBook` instance for it to act on. Did you mean for `ListOfBooks` to have a `NodeofBook` member?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NodeofBook` declaring that `ListofBooks` is a friend class just means that the implementation of `ListofBooks` can access `NodeofBook`'s private members, but there still needs to be an instance of `NodeofBook` to access. Its members are not static; non-static member variables are part of some object. That is, just because the `ListofBooks` is a friend of `NodeofBook` does not mean that it magically has instances of `NodeofBook`members.

A friend relationship is not an is-a relationship like inheritance: it is just about access.

Comment: Thank you!! I have been looking at this for over an hour without even realising I never created an instance of NodeofBook before trying to access it, cant believe i missed that! cheers